# xlup is looking for text, but finding formulas that are "", how to convert to look for non-'"/blank cells?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Counter = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row - 1
```

So I'm using this to look up occupied cells, but it's finding cells that have formulas that are IF's that end as "".

Can I convert this to look up visible text?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

### Last Row Excluding Cells Containing Formulas Evaluating to ""

**Using the `Find` method**

- Here is a [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) to see what Microsoft states about the `Find` method.
- Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba/11169920#11169920) to Siddharth Rout's legendary post about using the `Find` method to find the last cell (row).
- Note that `Counter` is 'pointing' one row above the Last Row.

**The Code**

```
Sub testGetLastRowInColumn()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Counter As Long

' Simple, for the ActiveSheet:
    LastRow = getLastRowInColumn("A") ' 1 or "A", both are allowed.
    Debug.Print LastRow

' Proper, for a certain sheet:
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' The workbook containing this code.
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    LastRow = getLastRowInColumn("A", ws)
    Debug.Print LastRow

' In your case
    LastRow = getLastRowInColumn(4)
    If LastRow > 0 Then
        Counter = LastRow - 1
    End If
    Debug.Print LastRow, Counter
    
' In your case without the function:
    LastRow = Columns(4).Find(What:="*", _
                              LookIn:=xlValues, _
                              SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    If LastRow > 0 Then
        Counter = LastRow - 1
    End If
    Debug.Print LastRow, Counter

' Or simplified:
    LastRow = Columns(4).Find("*", , xlValues, , , xlPrevious).Row
    If LastRow > 0 Then
        Counter = LastRow - 1
    End If
    Debug.Print LastRow, Counter

' Or just (if you're sure that there is data in column 4):
    Counter = Columns(4).Find("*", , xlValues, , , xlPrevious).Row - 1
    Debug.Print LastRow, Counter

End Sub

Function getLastRowInColumn(ColumnIndex As Variant, _
                            Optional Sheet As Worksheet = Nothing, _
                            Optional includeEmpties As Boolean = False)
    
    If Sheet Is Nothing Then
        Set Sheet = ActiveSheet
    End If
    
    Dim FormVal As XlFindLookIn
    If includeEmpties Then
        FormVal = xlFormulas
    Else
        FormVal = xlValues
    End If
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheet.Columns(ColumnIndex).Find(What:="*", _
                                              LookIn:=FormVal, _
                                              SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        getLastRowInColumn = rng.Row
    Else
        getLastRowInColumn = 0
    End If
    
End Function
```

Comment: ++ I forgot about `LookIn:=xlValues` in `.Find` :D Guess I am growing old

Comment: If you look at how many times I've edited the answer, you'll see I'm not better off either. Thx

Comment: That's a large code,. Is there a focus to any specific part?